# Check if what collection is updated in the database

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack, database

I am trying to edit a work that is created using Mean stack. Now i am comparing my database from local and database from the server. How can i know which collection is being updated everytime i am doing something in the server?

Everytime i am trying to check the webservice, the server returns value, while my local returns 0.

P.S. my copy of project in the local is the same as the copy of the project in the server

Answer (score 0):

Add logging to the backend layer. To the update and create methods in the restful service. Looking at the logs can tell you what was called.

You can also have LastUpdated datetime field for each collection and query the collections later to see which one got updated when.